# Disabled Input Will not Onclick Need a Way to Mark as Checked on Click

Tags: html, input, jscript

I just finished figuring out how to disable the input fields when the checkbox is clicked. And I have run into a second problem, a problem that has little support in answers and has a Firefox issue / Compatibility.

I wish to Be able to click the Input to enable the field again and mark the checkbox as checked. But I cannot figure it out and struggled to find answer.

Can anybody see a way around this with my code.

Thanks

```
<div style="position:relative; width:fit-content; height:fit-content; float:left; clear:both; margin-top:30px;">

<input type="checkbox" class='Xcheckbox' id="byname" name="searchforname" title='Search For All Listings With Sellers Name'  value="sellersname" onclick="chbxX(this); <?php $extrasearch==='sellersname'; ?>" <?php if ($extrasearch==='sellersname'):  ?> checked="checked" <?php endif; ?> ></input>

<label for="byname" class='nameheader' title='Search Date Range' ><b>Seller's Name</b></label>

<input type="text" id='byname2' name="SellersName" placeholder="Sellers Name" class="sellersname" title='Type The Sellers Name' disabled='true' onclick="uncheck();"; value="<?php echo $sellersname ?>"  ></input>
</div>

<script>

function uncheck(){         
document.getElementById('byname2').disabled=false;
chbxX(byname);
}

function chbxX(objX)
{

var that = objX;

(objX);

if(document.getElementById(that.id).checked === true) {

document.getElementById('byname').checked = false;
document.getElementById('bynumber').checked = false;
document.getElementById('bylistingid').checked = false;

document.getElementById('byname2').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('bynumber2').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('bylistingid2').disabled = true;

}
document.getElementById(that.id).checked = true;
document.getElementById(that.id+"2").disabled = false;
}

</script>
```